# How do you design methods to avoid making them non-testable?

Tags: c#

I want to unit test an extension method for a type [WebSiteResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.resourcemanager.appservice.websiteresource?view=azure-dotnet-preview), where this type `WebSiteResource` is an implementation of an `abstract` type. I need to set or mock a value to a property, but [it's not](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.resourcemanager.appservice.websitedata.defaulthostname?view=azure-dotnet-preview#azure-resourcemanager-appservice-websitedata-defaulthostname) `virtual`.

```
public static string HostName(this WebSiteResource webSite) => webSite.Data.DefaultHostName;
```

- I can't mock `WebSiteResource`, because it's not an interface
- I can't instantiate `WebSiteResource` because property `Data` requires complex setup
- I can't create a `MockableWebSiteResource` that inherits from `WebSiteResource` (and doing something like `public new virtual Data { get; set; }`) because `Data` requires complex setup

How do you design methods to avoid making them non-testable?

**Update (after answer):**

What I in fact have is a non-trivial method like

```
public static bool IsValid(this WebSiteResource webSite) {
   // and then complex logic for multiple properties etc
}
```

Comment: Your `HostName` method is so trivial, why do you feel you should write a unit-test for it?

Comment: You could try to create a wrapper class to encapsulate WebSiteResource and an interface for wrapper. Than you could mock and inject it easily.

Comment: @AleksejVasinov It's wrappers all the way down...

Comment: w.r.t your `bool IsValid` function... unfortunately there's no good solution for that. I do now understand and appreciate why you'd want to have tests for your logic in there - but I think that _even if_ you did painstakingly write all the wrappers and adapters to accomplish it, you'd only end-up duplicating application logic in your test-cases, making it entirely redundant. So I'd ask what the consequences-of-failure are: is this a safety-critical, high-reliability system? Or just some personal project? What do other people on your team think? _What's the harm in **not** having tests?_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to unit test an extension method...

The `string HostName()` method you posted is a trivial function: [I don't think there is any value in writing any kind of test code for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221566/unit-testing-of-extremely-trivial-methods-yes-or-no).

Automated tests are great, but they introduce their own brittleness and maintenance burden. If it took you 3 minutes to research and write that function, it's now going to take you *far more additional minutes* to think-up all the different weird and exotic edge-cases where your `HostName` function will fail (e.g. `website.Data is null` under some obscure network situation or race-condition).

---

Disregarding this *specific* function, but in general: regarding how to design *testable* code which directly consumes objects from opaque external libraries... well, the simple answer is *don't*: (as in: *don't write application code that directly consumes external library objects and directly passes those objects deeper into your own application code*).

So instead set-up clear boundaries: *software bulkheads* between distinct components in your application code and never let a naked external object cross that line. If you need to pass some data from an external library across the line then introduce *your own* POCO data-transfer-object and copy the values into it, then pass *that* along.

The alternative *path of least resistance* only leads to worse outcomes in the long-run: eventually every project in your solution has to reference all the same NuGet packages and assembly references so external library objects can be passed around (such as by passing that `WebSiteResource` object all the way directly to your user-interface).

....so you'll run into more and more of the problems like you've illustrated: even though it's *your project* you no-longer have any real control over the opaque objects you're using: in order to accomplish some future goal you'll likely find yourself fighting those libs and needing to write hackish code to work-around them instead of just directly editing their source and recompiling them, because you don't control them.

---

#### Sidebar: Personally, I blame C#'s inflexible type-system...

I note that a large *part* of this problem is simply because of how C# and the .NET CLR works: that **ultimately you're restricted from manipulating that `WebSiteResource` type (and its object-instances) by the .NET type-system** <sub>(...at least in Java everything is `virtual`)</sub>.

Because C#/.NET uses a nominative type-system that's strictly enforced by the runtime, and how it doesn't support structural-typing or true algebraic types it means we can't do things like `class HahahImSubclassingYouAnyway extends WebSiteResource` (or even `class HahahImSubclassingYouAnyway implements WebSiteResource` in some languages). At least we can use composition (which we *should* be doing anyway), but again, C#/.NET is still dragging its feet when it comes to making it easy to compose types together, not to mention how it's *impossible* to maintain reference identity (which is why we're forced to use inheritance-based subclassing in some situations).

Anyway, I'm ranting...

---

> I can't mock `WebSiteResource`, because it's not an interface

- Assuming you're [still dead-set on this](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fool%27s%20errand), then implement your own adapter types.

  - Yes, it's exactly as tedious and error-prone as it sounds.
  - *Yes*, this is why it's probably an inappropriate use of your time to work on this.

> I can't instantiate `WebSiteResource` because property `Data` requires complex setup

The fact you wrote that makes it sound like you're thinking of writing test-cases that will essentially test the `WebSiteResource` object far more than your own code. I know that's not your intention, though.

> I can't create a `MockableWebSiteResource` that inherits from `WebSiteResource` (and doing something like `public new virtual Data { get; set; }`) because `Data` requires complex setup

Whoa, stop, *hold it right there*...

What you're describing is an abuse of OOP inheritance. Your proposed `MockableWebSiteResource` clearly shouldn't have an "is" conceptual relationship with `WebSiteResource`, but that's exactly what OOP class inheritance represents (and `WebSiteResource` represents a fully-fleshed out service implementation, not an abstract service). This is a sign that *something isn't right* with your approach. Stop. Think. Reconsider.

(And because [Java](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mt7zsortIXs)[-style OOP inheritance (which C# shares) is so limiting and inelegant it just ends-up *creating* problems instead of solving them: it's just *bad*](https://boxbase.org/entries/2020/aug/3/case-against-oop/). I'm sure you've run into situations where you found it impossible to use OOP inheritance for any kind of direct [domain modelling](https://wiki.c2.com/?TheValueOfDomainModels)).

<sub>(With apologies to Smalltalk and Simula fans (we love you), but I'm using the term "OOP" in the Java-family sense: so I am not referring to the broader (or *purer*) higher-minded concepts of O.G. OOP where message-passing and delegation are used instead of virtual methods and inheritance)</sub>

> How do you design methods to avoid making them non-testable?

I can't give you anything other than general guidelines that we've all head before:

- [Writing "unit testable" code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007458/writing-unit-testable-code)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/288405/is-testable-code-better-code
- Somewhat contrary to my advice to define your own service/adapter types, [this recent article from StackOverflow recommends testing with "real" services](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/01/03/favor-real-dependencies-for-unit-testing/) (of course that would be an integration-test, not a unit test...). But I digress.
- Think critically, of course: https://medium.com/@first.last/unit-testing-the-worst-of-stackoverflow-2fef3bd85ed9

Comment: Thanks, my example `HostName` was maybe not good. What I in fact have is a method like `public static bool IsValid(this WebSiteResource webSite) { // and then complex logic for multiple properties ec }`. But I get your point about setting up clear boundaries. Good explanation!

Comment: @KristofferJälén I hope by "composition" you don't mean "wrappers of wrappers" and [maybe some Enterprise-y design-patterns thrown in for good measure](https://github.com/EnterpriseQualityCoding/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition).

Comment: Oh, it becomes clearer.. I guess I can't unit test the `IsValid` method, just as you write in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72199008/how-do-you-design-methods-to-avoid-making-them-non-testable#comment127563300_72199008).